# Submitting advanced ebay searches with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web, web-scraping

I know there's an API among other things for scraping ebay but all I need is to submit advanced searches.

So, I made a function to do this, (hardcoded for now) but there's one thing I cannot get to work. It's marking items as new.

From inspecting the element on their form when items are marked as `New` in the advanced search form the other two fields get marked as `disabled` and that's the only changes I could see.

I'm submitting the form as below and writing the content to a file so I can open it up to see the result.

Everything works fine and I can open the webpage and it's the correct results, but the `New` option is not selected.

What is the correct way to submit this selection? I've tried lots of variations and nothing I've tried works.

```
def submit_advanced_search():

    params = {
        '_nkw': "",
        '_in_kw': 1,
        '_ex_kw': "",
        '_sacat': 20081,
        'LH_Sold': 1,
        '_udlo': 20,
        '_udhi': 250,
        'LH_ItemConditionUsed': {'disabled':'disabled'},
        'LH_ItemConditionNS': {'disabled':'disabled'},
        'LH_BIN': 1,
        'LH_FS': 1,
        'LH_Complete': 1,
    }

    content = requests.get("http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html", params = params).content
    with open("search_result.html", "wb") as f:
        f.write(content)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what worked for me. The correct field is `'LH_ItemCondition': 3`.

So the function would be:

```
def submit_advanced_search():

    params = {
        '_nkw': "",
        '_in_kw': 1,
        '_ex_kw': "",
        '_sacat': 20081,
        'LH_Sold': 1,
        '_udlo': 20,
        '_udhi': 250,
        'LH_ItemCondition': 3,
        'LH_BIN': 1,
        'LH_FS': 1,
        'LH_Complete': 1,
    }

    content = requests.get("http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html", params = params).content
    with open("search_result.html", "wb") as f:
        f.write(content)
```